# How to identify whether S3 requests being signed with SigV2 or SigV4?

Tags: amazon-s3

I have recently upgraded AWS Java SDK dependency to its latest version 1.11.x, for S3 requests. Now, how do I identify whether the requests are being signed with SigV2 or SigV4?